# Which tools were used to create the C language?

Tags: history, c, compilers

Was the original C compiler written in some old assembly language and now later [flex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flex_(lexical_analyser_generator)) and [bison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_bison) are used instead?

Comment: https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/chist.html

Comment: [It was written in C](https://github.com/mortdeus/legacy-cc). What do "flex and bison" have to do with anything?

Comment: What are flex and bison?

Comment: They're two GNU tools that together automate generation of parsers and lexical analysers — so you can skip ahead to implementing whatever your compiler does when various structures are observed, rather than having to start from  dealing with text and recognising tokens, and hence expressions or statements or anything else your language might define.

Comment: But C existed well before flex and bison (and GNU). The predecessors of flex and bison were lex and yacc.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that modern compilers like `gcc` normally don't use generated lexers and parsers anymore.

Comment: Orignally "lex" and "yacc" were written to help writing small domain specific tools (you need to read some input files in some form).  These were reimplemented for GNU as "flex" and "bison" (pun!).  These days data tends to be carried in a form that already can be parsed, like JSON.

Comment: This [Hacker News thread](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=26420214) might contain some information not already covered in existing answers.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

C didn't spring into being suddenly, but was created by slowly modifying the [B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B_(programming_language)) language--which was written in itself.  Therefore you might say that C was always written in itself, but at first it was just a slightly modified B.

Dennis Ritchie describes the evolution of C in [The Development of the C Language](http://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/chist.html).  He started by making small improvements to the B language:

> In 1971 I began to extend the B language by adding a character type and also rewrote its compiler to generate PDP-11 machine instructions instead of threaded code. Thus the transition from B to C was contemporaneous with the creation of a compiler capable of producing programs fast and small enough to compete with assembly language. I called the slightly-extended language NB, for `new B.'

Eventually, he made enough changes that the language deserved a new name:

> After creating the type system, the associated syntax, and the compiler for the new language, I felt that it deserved a new name; NB seemed insufficiently distinctive. I decided to follow the single-letter style and called it C, leaving open the question whether the name represented a progression through the alphabet or through the letters in BCPL.

Comment: So was there also a language called "A" that B was originally written in?

Comment: @coderworks [B](http://enwp.org/B) was written in [BCPL](http://enwp.org/BCPL) which was written in [CPL](http://enwp.org/CPL), which was written in and influenced by [ALGOL 60](http://enwp.org/ALGOL_60). So in a roundabout way, kind of.

Comment: @coderworks by the way, [D](http://enwp.org/D_%28programming_language%29) is also written in C (and D) :D

Comment: @cat +1 to your comment for your punny smiley.  I typically don't favor the :D variation of a smiley, but in this case it was the most appropriate.  Kudos.

Comment: @TOOGAM Oh, I appreciate your PhD thesis of a comment on why you upvoted ;)

Answer (score 12):

As is evident from its name, YACC (Yet Another Compiler Compiler) was not the first compiler writing aid. Its predecessor was the [TMG](http://www.multicians.org/tmg.html) tool.

> TMG was the compiler definition tool used by Ken Thompson to write the compiler for the B language on his PDP-7 in 1970. B was the immediate ancestor of C.

The `tmg` executable can still be seen on the UNIX V6 disks, along with `yacc`. In UNIX V7, AFAIR, `tmg` was already omitted.

Comment: There were many many others besides TMG. Floyd described one in the Floyd Production Language paper around 1963; WIlliam Waite had one in the late 1960s; many others. Hence 'yet another'.

Comment: @EJP Sure, but it was specifically TMG that figured in the development lineage of the C language.

Comment: The original "compiler compiler" (by that name) was [written by Tony Brooker and Derrick Morris in 1960](http://www.chilton-computing.org.uk/acl/applications/cc/p007.htm#s2p3).